# How to add MicrosoftTeams list of members with PowerShell commands?

Tags: microsoft-teams, list

I wanted to add a list of members to Microsoft Teams but couldn't do it easily like adding multiple emails in gmail.

I read in a link that I can use PowerShell commands but I get error results.

[image: powershell]

---

Update1:
After getting the solution in the first answer, I was able to pass the first error. In the previous picture.

Now I want to proceed and run the rest of commands and I reached this command and can't get through it.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
```

This is the error message on PowerShell:

[image: issue 2]

This is the link I got the idea from:
[Adding bulk users from a .csv file to a Microsoft Teams team](https://medium.com/@joaquin.guerrero/adding-bulk-users-from-a-csv-file-to-a-microsoft-teams-team-374414b9d8c9)

---

Update2:

I tried the next commands you provided but here's a picture. I have problems running the commands.

[image]

It could be some admin privileges I don't have in my rig, even I tried before to set myself as the main admin of the rig.

But anyway I solved the issue from another perspective. I used some excel functions to lookup the numbers I want and solved the problem that I wanted to run these commands for which is to add members in bulk for Microsoft Teams.

Comment: What commands are you running?

Comment: The first one didn't work, that is listed in the link.

Comment: So we need to guess which one? Can't you show an entire PowerShell session?

Comment: OK, I'm trying another way that seem to be much easier, would you like me to post its picture in the main post or continue with PowerShell commands ?

Comment: OK, I added a picture in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Run PowerShell as admin and try this command:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

If the above command fails, enter the command below and then try again
the above command:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Once NuGet is installed, open a PowerShell window and run the
following command to Install the Microsoft Teams Module:

```
Install-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

Run the following command to add Teams module to the current session:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

Run the following commands to connect to Microsoft Teams:

```
$credentials=Get-Credential   
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credentials
```

Run the following command to get all the teams:

```
Get-Team
```

Comment: Yep, worked with the 2nd command and activated the first one.

Comment: I couldn't run this command `Connect-MicrosoftTeams`

Comment: I posted update 1 in the main post.

Comment: I added more info.